# Edge cases for a multistep navigation on mobile

Tags: navigation, mobile-application, multi-step

Working on an ecommerce app feature where each product will have a multistep horizontal navigation (refer below). however the amount of steps might vary form 1-4. can't seem to come up with a decent way to show only one step without breaking the consistency of the other multistep navigations on the same screen. what would be the best approach. go for consistancy or come up with something new?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't know what the end state of all of these steps is but my assumption is that there would be a CTA to finish the process.

If so you can just use that as the final click after step 1..> finish

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to show the number of steps for a single step process?

Surely you only need the user to recognise a multi-step process when it IS a multi-step process - ie when there are 2 or more steps.

My recommendation would be to abandon the single step indication all together.